# SSIS Cache Mamnager

Tags: ssis, data-integration

Is it possible to use an SSIS Cache manger with anything other than a Lookup?  I would like to use similar data across multiple data flows.

I haven't been able to find a way to cache this data in memory in a cache manager and then reuse it in a later flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, a cache connection manager was specific to solving lookup tasks originally only allowing an OLE DB Connection to be used.

However, if you have a set of data you want to be static for the life of a package run and able to be used across data flows, or even other packages, as a table-like entity, perhaps you're looking for a [Raw File](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2019/09/03/using-raw-files-in-ssis/). It's a tight, binary implementation of the data stored to disk. Since it's stored to disk, you will pay a write and subsequent read performance penalty but it's likely that the files are right sized such that any penalty is offset by the specific needs.

The first step you will need to do is define the data that will go into a Raw file and connect a [Raw File Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-destination?view=sql-server-ver15). Which is going to involve creating a Raw File Connection Manager where you will define where the file lives and the rules about the data in there (recreate, append, etc). At this point, run the data flow task so the file is created and populated.

The next step is everywhere you want to use the data, you'll patch in a [Raw File Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/raw-file-source?view=sql-server-ver15). It's going to behave much as any other data source in your toolkit at this point.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for.  I was going that way but I wanted to make sure about the cache manager.